# Readable highwatermark usefulness

Tags: node.js, stream

Does `highWaterMark` have an utility when implementing a Readable stream if we do not take care of it in the `_read()` method?

If I understand it correctly, it is to the programmer sole discretion to cease the reading, and if he does not, nothing will throttle it (not even `pipe`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** yes it has, but it's not something you need to worry about. :)

You're right, the highWaterMark does not have any influence on the actual reading (or generating data) but it does have direct influence on `Readable.._read` or rather it influences the information you get from `Readable..push`. So despite you don't need to and you shouldn't include any logic based on it in your `_read` implementation - it does have an utility.

To explain let's start with the docs on [Readable.._read](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size_1) - `_read` is called when the stream data is below `_highWaterMark` ideally before reaching the point when `drain` event needs to be emitted. Whenever the method is called it blocks further calls before the `push` method is called by the implementation.

So what you're saying, there's nothing keeping you from writing this implementation:

```
_read(sizeRequired) {
    const x = readLotsOfChunksDisregardingSizeRequired();
    x.forEach(chunk => this.push(chunk);
}
```

And sure, that's true and in some cases, where you can't really control the read it can be acceptable. However the `_highWaterMark` is also used to give you quick back-information in the `push` method.

So if we consider another implementation where you can control the source:

```
_read(numRequired) {
    while (true) { // I know, I know don't write while true's...
        const chunk = readASingleChunk();
        if (!this.push(chunk))
            return;
    }
}
```

In this case the `_highWaterMark` machinery will be checked after each chunk written and if you actually reach the `highWaterMark` `this.push(chunk)` will return `false` and your stream will use as little memory as needed and will also keep flowing at a sensible rate.

Remember that the implementation you're writing can be read in a streamed fashion, where it will be piped to a writeable stream. The `highWaterMark` makes sure that the stream is constantly flowing and the memory used to keep that state is used effectively.

Comment: Pleasure is mine. I like streams, mountain and otherwise. ;)